# Git is conflicting during merge, but the file looks the same. Why?

Tags: git, merge, cherry-pick

I'm getting a merge conflict on a file that looks to be exactly the same in both branches.

1. First the change was made to dev.
2. Second hand copied to mybranch.
3. Merge mybranch into dev

I need to merge mybranch into dev, and this is what I get: (showing an internal requirejs like pkg system file)

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
/* requires /js/my.js */ 
=======
/* requires /js/my.js */
>>>>>>> mybranch
/* requires /js/awesome.js */
```

git diff: Still confused :D

```
index 84a44e6..11fa0ea 100644
--- a/src/main/js/pkgFile.js
+++ b/src/main/js/pkgFile.js
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-/* requires /js/my.js */
-/* requires /js/awesome.js */
\ No newline at end of file
+/* requires /js/my.js */
+/* requires /js/awesome.js */
\ No newline at end of file
```

Why would I be getting any conflict at all when it looks like the exact same code?
Isn't git smart enough to figure things out?

Comment: Are the line endings the same?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was primarily a whitespace issue. I ran the merge with the following command:

```
git merge -Xignore-space-change mybranch
```

And didn't see the conflicts anymore. Awesome.

Comment: If you use [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) as `mergetool`it will nicely highlight and show whitespace differences.